# Como criar um TJSonObject/TJSonArray complexo com XE2

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

Preciso criar um Json complexo, com varios objetos, sendo que cada objeto, tera itens;

```
{
"Pedidos": [
    {
        "CodCad": "1286",
        "CodForPag": "15",
        "CodCndPag": "43",
        "CodUndAdm": "1",
        "DatEmi": "19/05/2021",
        "DatSol": "26/04/2021 21:42:00",
        "PesCnt": "GLADSON",
        "Tel": "0000000000",
        "Sta": "0",
        "Itens": [
            {
                "CodPro": "310",
                "CodUnd": "66",
                "Qtd": "10",
                "Vlr": "11",
                "Und": "UN",
                "Cmp": "0",
                "Lrg": "0",
                "M2m": "0",
                "Sta": "0",
                "VlrDsc": "0",
                "VlrTot": "110",
                "PrdSrv": "0",
                "NumRqc": "",
                "NumMapCol": "1",
                "EspExt": "60PVD",
                "QtdAtd": "0"
            },
            {
                "CodPro": "3251",
                "CodUnd": "66",
                "Qtd": "3",
                "Vlr": "15",
                "Und": "UN",
                "Cmp": "0",
                "Lrg": "0",
                "M2m": "0",
                "Sta": "0",
                "VlrDsc": "0",
                "VlrTot": "45",
                "PrdSrv": "0",
                "NumRqc": "",
                "NumMapCol": "1",
                "EspExt": "",
                "QtdAtd": "0"
            }
        ]
    },
    ...
    ...
]
```

}

Percebo que quando eu crio um TJsonObjet e TJsonArray, e vou dar um `Free` neles me geram uma violação.

```
JSon := TJsonObject.Create();
APedidos := TJsonArray.Create();
while not cdsMapOrd001.Eof do
begin
```

Eu preciso usar FreeAndNil em todos os objetos criados ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aqui os objetos são passados como referência, então, cuidado na hora de destruir.
Vamos lá.

O processo é simples, aqui é como os Nós do XML, temos Pai e Filho.
Neste mundo, se você destruir um Pai o filho automaticamente será destruído.

Portanto, ao tentar destruir um filho ocorrerá uma violação.

Exemplo da estrutura:

```
var
  i: Integer;
  vJsonResultado: TJSONObject;
  vJsonItensArray: TJSONObject;
  vJsonItens: TJSONArray;
begin
  vJsonResultado := TJSONObject.Create;
  vJsonResultado.AddPair('codigo', '0');

  vJsonItens := TJSONArray.Create;

  for i := 1 to 2 do
  begin
    vJsonItensArray := TJSONObject.Create;
    vJsonItensArray.AddPair(1.ToString, DateToStr(Now));

    vJsonItens.AddElement(vJsonItensArray);
  end;

  vJsonResultado.AddPair('mensagem', vJsonItens);

  FreeAndNil(vJsonResultado);
end;
```

Observe que estamos destruindo apenas o `vJsonResultado`;

Ative em seu projeto a propriedade `ReportMemoryLeaksOnShutdown` assim você consegue compreender onde esta vazando memória.

`ReportMemoryLeaksOnShutdown := True`

Comment: Muito obrigado. Esclarecido. Conforme o que vc disse eu pesquisei e encontrei este tópico : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44584751/reportmemoryleaksonshutdown-not-working-in-delphi-10-2-tokyo e a resposta fala do Xe2.

Comment: Eu não entendi o uso do ```ReportMemoryLeaksOnShutdown := True``` Ele apresenta uma tela com muita informação, mas nada em detalhes. Voce teria alguma sugestão para estudos ?

Comment: Essa tela que aparece com MUITA informação esta te dizendo o que ficou em sua aplicação sem ser destruído.

Comment: Complementando a resposta do Junior, aconselho verificar com if Assigned(vJsonResultado) then na finalização do objeto. Assim como os outros objetos criados e remover da memória com vJsonResultado := nil; vJsonResultado.Free. Pois manipulação com objetos JSON pode dar problema com "erro de ponteiro" ao finalizar FreeAndNil().